# Как убрать отображение визуального редактора в WordPress 4.9.8?

Tags: wordpress

Как убрать отображение визуального редактора в WordPress 4.9.8?

Comment: Если кому-то непонятна суть такого примитивного вопроса по WordPress, то лучше в эту метку не заходить вообще. Голосуйте за закрытие в другом месте.

Answer (score 2):

В профиле пользователя есть галка "Отключить визуальный редактор". Используйте её.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]